# Hide specific items (set in SharedPreferences) in RecyclerView

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-recyclerview

I want to filter/hide specific Items in the RecycleView if the item content matches with an preference set in SharedPreferences.

I guess I have to somehow prevent from these specific items from getting inflated in the adapter but I have no idea how.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An adapter is the Model part of the Model-View-Controller design pattern for using `ListView`, `GridView`, and `RecyclerView`.  So you have to think of it this way:  The adapter, *at any moment*, has to reflect what you want to have displayed in the `RecyclerView`.

So here's an example:  Let's say you have four items, and you want to filter the third item because it matches your preference.  Your adapter's `getCount()` method must return `3`.   For `getView()`, position == 0 must return the first item view, position == 1 must return your second item view, and position == 2 must return your *fourth* item view.

It's up to your adapter code to figure out all calculations and offsets to make sure that it is always presenting a consistent state to the view.  So for example, let's say you have a `String` array with the items, and an index `dontshow` pointing to the array item that shouldn't be displayed.  You need to do something like this for `getView()`:

```
int index = position;  // position is input parameter
if (index >= dontshow) {
    index++;   // skip over the don't-show item
}
String item = items[index];
// now construct your view from this item
```

And

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length - 1;
}
```

Then when you make changes to your model, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` tells the `RecyclerView` it has to call `getCount()` and `getView()` on your adapter all over again to redisplay the changed data.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it now. Even though I solved my specific problem by removing the information before it got to the adapter in the first place.